# Prove additive inverse in vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

When you scale a vector by $-1$, it is the same as taking the additive inverse:

$$-\vec V = -1 \cdot \vec V.$$

Can someone please help me to prove this?

Comment: "scale" just means to multiply by a scalar.  Doesn't need to be $-1$.

Comment: sorry for the mistake, now it is clear.

Answer (score 3):

Using properties of vector spaces, $-1\cdot \vec v +\vec v = -1\cdot \vec v + 1 \cdot \vec v = (-1+1)\cdot \vec v= 0\cdot \vec v= \vec 0,$ so $-1\cdot \vec v$ is the additive inverse of $\vec v$ (i.e., $-\vec v). $

Answer (score 1):

Multiplication by a positive scalar changes the magnitude of a vector but not the direction, negative scalar changes the magnitude oand reverses the direction, therefore when the scalar is $-1$

$$\vec v + (-1)\cdot \vec v=\vec v +(-\vec v) =\vec v - \vec v=\vec 0$$

therefore $-1\cdot \vec v$ is the additive inverse of $\vec v$.

Comment: How do you add another vector, I didn't get this. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @HariBharathi If we add to any vector $\vec v$ the vector $-1\cdot \vec v$ we obtain the zero vector. That is $-1\cdot \vec v$ is the additive inverse of $\vec v$.

Comment: Thanks much for your explanation.

Comment: @HariBharathi You are welcome! Bye

Comment: Your first equality presupposes that $(-1)v=-v$.  I think you need to use the distributive property like J.W. Tanner does to establish this fact.